# nginx - config for several domains

Tags: web-server, nginx, configuration

So in the past, I've just had one nginx.conf file. I'd like to separate this out for each domain (right now there's two), but to stay organized in case there's more.

How is this possible to let each domain have it's own .conf file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.. This is how I do it in the nginx.conf in the http {} block I do

```
include /etc/nginx/vhosts.d/*.conf;
```

Then each vhost has its own seperate vhost file. To make it easy they are named like

```
/etc/nginx/vhosts.d/domain1.com.conf
/etc/nginx/vhosts.d/otherdomain.net.conf
```

In those files you have your normal server {} blocks for the vhost